# dbplyr copy_to not saving table to database

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, dbplyr

I am trying to copy a local dataframe from R to my db2 database.  I have permissions to write to the table and I have verified the connection is working.

I am using:

```
copy_to(connection, data.frame, name = my_table_name)
```

I am getting the following error and it doesnt make sense to me.  The object it says does not exist is the very object I am trying to create.  What am I doing wrong?

> Error in typeof(x) : object 'my_table_name' not found

Comment: Try copy_to(connection, data.frame, name = "my_table_name")

Comment: @DMC thanks for the reply.  That seems to have bypassed the original error, however a new error has occurred:                                                       Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1344: 42000: [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token TEMPORARY was not valid. Valid tokens: SUMMARY.

Comment: @DMC is this error generated because of the size of the table I am trying to copy?

Comment: The fact that "Token" was mentioned indicates it is a permissions issue

Answer (score 6):

by default, `copy_to()` tries to create a temporary table.  An option is to add the argument `temporary = FALSE`, to overcome the `TEMPORARY` token error.  A better solution is for the package that you are using to connect, which is hopefully the `odbc` package, is for it to add support for DB2 databases.  In other words, `odbc` will need to know what is the specific command needed to properly create a temporary table.  Once that's fixed, `copy_to()` will work.  If it's indeed the `odbc` package that you are using, I would recommend that you open a GitHub issue in the package's repo.

Comment: I just needed to add `copy_to(..., temporary=FALSE)` and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by an issue with `DBI` not `dbplyr`. See [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/257). There is a work around that draws on the `DBI` package. you can more details on it [here](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/schema/#write-non-temporary-tables).

In summary: The DBI package has a write table command. It uses the same connection, but it also requires that the input table name is wrapped in `SQL()`.

I tested the following and it worked as expected.

```
data(iris)
DBI::dbWriteTable(connection, SQL("database.schema.iris"), iris)
```